# "No such file or directory" appears when I run "sudo chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.63.run"

Tags: nvidia

I use Ubuntu 15.10.

I am following the instructions [here](http://www.ubuntumaniac.com/2015/11/install-nvidia-linux-display-driver.html) to install the Nvidia Linux Display Driver 352.63. I am aware that I have to disable my X Server before installing it, so I press `Ctrl + Alt + F1` to log in, and run the command `sudo service lightdm stop`.

The first step `wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/352.63/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.63.run` works fine.

The problem arises when I try to run the second command, `sudo chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.63.run`. I keep receiving the error message `No such file or directory`.

Any advice?

**EDIT:**

This is the output when I run `ls -l`:

```
drwxrwxr-x 17 me me     4096 Mär 23 13:09 anaconda2
drwxrwxr-x  2 me me     4096 Mär 22 13:50 bin
-rw-------  1 root             root             13991936 Mär 23 14:44 core
drwxrwxr-x  3 me me     4096 Mär 22 15:46 cuda
drwxr-xr-x  4 me me     4096 Mär 22 17:57 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me     4096 Mär 20 13:37 Documents
drwxr-xr-x  7 me me     4096 Mär 23 13:55 Downloads
-rw-r--r--  1 me me     8980 Mär 20 13:35 examples.desktop
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me        0 Mär 21 12:40 log
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me     4096 Mär 22 18:23 MNIST_data
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me     4096 Mär 20 13:37 Music
-rwxrwxr-x  1 me me 77647248 Nov  9 18:49 NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.63.run
drwxr-xr-x  3 me me     4096 Mär 22 16:23 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me     4096 Mär 20 13:37 Public
drwxrwxr-x  8 me me     4096 Mär 22 18:50 pycharm-community-5.0.4
drwxrwxr-x  3 me me     4096 Mär 22 19:09 PycharmProjects
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me     4096 Mär 20 13:37 Templates
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me     4096 Mär 20 13:37 Videos
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `ls -l`

Comment: @CarlH Done :-)

Comment: This is a really bad idea to install this driver from a `.run` file.

Comment: @Pilot6 Why? This is my first time using a Linux distribution so I am genuinely curious.

Comment: Because this way you will have to re-install the driver after each kernel update. After you install some update with a kernel package, the system will not boot. You will get a black screen.

Comment: Because many drivers need to recompile parts for each version of the Linux kernel (which gets updates *all* the time). The version included with Ubuntu has a script which does this automatically. The installer version needs to be run manually. It's a pain in the bottom.

Comment: The driver form Nvidia site is published to be packed to deb packages for Ubuntu, that is done by Ubuntu maintainers or by PPA maintainers for the very latest ones.

Comment: Edit your post to include the output of `file NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.63.run` and `uname -a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the same driver a correct way by running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

Or go to System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers

and install it from there.

But the 352.63 driver has a bug, that leads to system dead hangs on some adapters. It has been fixed in 352.79.

It can be installed from a PPA this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to options:

1. Give full path to the file:
   `sudo chmod +x /path/to/file`
2. Run directly with `sh`:
   `sudo sh /path/to/file`